# Запустить приложение в отдельном окне, получить output из subprocess.Popen и распарсить его

Tags: python-3.x

Делаю так:

```
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(['netdump', '-i', 'wlan0'], start_new_session=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Процесс "netdump" появляется, но не в отдельном окне. Как его сделать запускаемым в отдельном окне и разобрать то, что netdump там понаписал ?

UPD: Вот мой же ответ

```
cmd = 'netdump -i wlan0'
result = subprocess.run(["xterm", "-e", cmd], capture_output=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = 'netdump -i wlan0'
result = subprocess.run(["xterm", "-e", cmd], capture_output=True)
```